# PHP query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It's my first experience with programming and I can't solve this problem. I found code in tutorial, but it won't work for me.

List won't show data from database, but in table it all works.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixWt4.png)

My code:

```
<?php
$servername = "111";
$username = "1111";
$password = "111";
$dbname = "1111";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Region_ID, Region_Name FROM Regions"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    echo "<select name='Choose Region'>";
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['Region_Namee'] ."'>" . $v['Region_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: `catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}` Is this returning any error?

Comment: That's some stupid tutorial. Change foreach line to `foreach($stmt as $v)`

Comment: Look at the source of the page. Maybe the values aren't quite what you think they are. And why are you using `Region_Namee` when you aren't fetching it?

Comment: @aynber I repaired it before, sorry in image wrong. Still dont work.

Comment: @TylerRoper Nope, no message

Comment: Try @YourCommonSense's comment.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, It worked. :) Very helpfull :) and tutorial from w3schools

Comment: Some dude wrote a tutorial shoving an overly overcomplicated way to complicate things when working with PDO. No idea what were his reasons.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, maybe you know more simple tutorials? :) It would be very nice. Becouse, anyone said me, that I need to learn from w3school

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I think the fault lies with  w3schools  for not taking any reviews of their content seriously. Recommendations of specific improvements are disregarded and ignored. Try it some time, try suggesting an improvement to that tutorial...  I've done it before. I'm done messing with w3fools and the bad coding practices that they promote.

Comment: Oh they did you wrong. w3fools is actually the worst source ever. I've got a [tutorial of my own](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn), though it could be not that simple. But at least it won't tell you any rubbish. For the moment you need only the first 12 chatpers

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you, Man. You'r a good guy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record. PDO is excellent extension that can make your code dramatically shorter. It can do a lot of things for you. But many tutorials will teach you to reinvent a lot of wheels already existing in PDO. If take all the rubbish out you'll see that PDO is actually giving you the cleanest code possible:

```
<?php
$servername = "111";
$username = "1111";
$password = "111";
$dbname = "1111";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// everything above this line should go into separate file
// and just gets included here

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT Region_ID, Region_Name FROM Regions"); 
echo "<select name='Choose Region'>";
foreach ($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['Region_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Region_Name'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

the rest is handled by PDO